# Pylint invalid syntax (<string>, line ...) (syntax-error) Because of accent character

Tags: python, pylint

When I run Pylint without accentuated characters, it runs fine. When I have a class name like Café, I get the syntax error. I'm on a Mac.
Tried to find how to configure that without success.

Comment: Python 2.7, which is installed by default on Macs, only supports ASCII characters in identifiers.  You'd need to install a 3.x version to allow names like `Café`.

Comment: Thanks @jasonharper , I had both installed but pylint was running with the 2.7 version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was running pylint but underneath it was using python 2.7 which as @jasonharper said is ASCII only.

I installed pylint with :
python -m pip install -U pylint

Note that I have an alias that makes my python commands run as python3.

Now it works